# Sony Tablet Keyboard popup issue

Tags: scrollview, android-activity, android, sony

Does anyone else have an idea on how to fix a very annoying issue on a Sony Tablet S.

I have a vertical ScrollView and a linearlayout with lots of TextViews and some EditTexts.  When I scroll down the screen and an EditText comes into view the device decides to give the EditText focus and pop up the keyboard.

This doesn't happen on other devices such as Asus Transformer Prime, HTC One X, Samsung Galaxy Tab and a HP TouchPad (cyanogenmod).

Things I've done.

- Windows Soft Input mode is set to "stateHidden" in the manifest for the activity.
- There is a LinearLayout at the top of stack that has focusable and focusable in touch set to true.
- The code will also give this layout the focus on create.

It definitely seems to be a Sony Tablet specific problem!

Anyone else had this issue and a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add an eventListener on EditText, when it gains focus then hide the keyboard

by using this:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

---

to get focus gain event use this function

```
imageView.setOnFocusChangeListener(
    new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
            // hide the keyboard using above code
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });
```

Hopefully it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the code.  Unfortunately it has no effect.  Same problem with the keyboard popping up as I scroll down the screen.

Comment: The code does not have the right effect on HTC Desire running 2.2.1. The keyboard does not appear, but the bottom half of the screen does scroll up (where the keyboard would show). I just post this to give input on other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed the ICS update.  Problem has now vanished!

Answer (score 0):

Try posting a runnable on a view.

```
editText.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
   }
});
```